# How can I modify my code so that gives me seemly output?

Tags: c++

my input is like this (the first two line of input):

```
{4 <1,-1,-1> <1,1,-1> <-1,1,-1> <-1,-1,-1>} //first line
{4 <1,3,-1> <1,1,-1> <1,1,0.5> <1,3,0.5>}
{4 <1,3,-1> <-1,3,-1> <-1,1,-1> <1,1,-1>}
{4 <-1,3,-1> <-1,3,0.5> <-1,1,0.5> <-1,1,-1>}
{4 <1,3,0.5> <1,1,0.5> <0.75,1,1> <0.75,3,1>}
{4 <-0.75,3,1> <-0.75,1,1> <-1,1,0.5> <-1,3,0.5>}
{4 <-0.75,3,1> <0.75,3,1> <0.75,1,1> <-0.75,1,1>}
{4 <1,-1,0.5> <1,-0.75,1> <3,-0.75,1> <3,-1,0.5>}
{4 <1,-1,0.5> <3,-1,0.5> <3,-1,-1> <1,-1,-1>}
{4 <1,-1,-1> <3,-1,-1> <3,1,-1> <1,1,-1>} //tenth line
```

I have a code like this, which I expected to read each bracket in order, namely 1,-1,-1, then search them in input file to fine similar bracket and showing them, but it does not:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;

using vecstr = vector<string>;

vecstr splitOut(const string &line) {
  size_t  pos = 0;
  vecstr result;
  while ( (pos=line.find('<',pos)) != string::npos ) {
    size_t endpos = line.find('>',pos);
    if ( endpos != string::npos ) {
      string token = line.substr(pos+1,endpos-pos-1);
      result.push_back(token);
    } else {

    }
    pos = endpos;
  }
  return result;
}

int main ( ) {

    ifstream iss("a.txt");
    string line;
    int offset;
    unsigned int curLine = 0;

    while (getline(iss,line)){
        string test = line;
        vecstr result = splitOut(test);
        for ( auto s : result ) {

            while(getline(iss, line)) { 
                curLine++;
                if ((offset = line.find(s, 0)) != string::npos) {
                cout << "found: " << s << " line: " << curLine << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all of output that code shows (I mean it does not consider other brackets as well as the lines showed for first line are incorrect, they should be 9 and 10):

```
found: 1,-1,-1 line: 8
found: 1,-1,-1 line: 9
```

how can I change program to show me an output like this (for example for first bracket, i.e. 1,-1,-1):

```
found: 1,-1,-1 line: 9
found: 1,-1,-1 line: 10
```

Comment: You asked (and deleted) the same question a few hours ago. What changed between this question and that?

Comment: one person said your question is long, and also said "post a minimal reproducible example of your question".

Comment: You seem to be writing your c++ like a c programmer, lee.  Depending on your purpose, why not make more use of istream, or use regex, or even use a lexer - eg in boost::spirit?  cf. https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/warming_up.html

Comment: you could have edited the question to fix it. Not sure, but I think you can even delete a question, edit and then undelete it

Comment: you nicely reduced the code, but you reduced the input too much. Especially the lines you expect to see in the output are missing. Do you want to start counting the lines at 0 or at 1? The code seems to start at 1...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 yes, it commences from 1.

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>` -- Try this -- The key in the map is the bracket string, value is a vector of line numbers where the string is found.  If the vector has > 1 item, then you know the string was duplicated, plus the line numbers are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to find the line numbers of  number triples that occur multiple times.
I suggest keeping a `unordered_map<string, int>` that maps each triple to the first line you saw it in.

You can then structure your program as follows:

- For each line, get the triples present on the line. (you have this already)
- For each triple:

  - if it is present in the map you found a recurring triple, so report it with the line stored in the map and the current line number.
  - if it is not present, add it with the current line number.

You can easily change the behavior of your program by using a more complex value type than `int`. For example, by keeping a `pair<int, bool>` you could record only the first recurrence and then stop. Or you a `pair<int, int>` to record both the first occurrence and the number of recurrences afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I do not really understand the logic of your code, or how you get the output you get. Anyhow, I am pretty sure that this cannot be correct...

Here:

```
while (getline(iss,line)){
    string test = line;
    vecstr result = splitOut(test);
    for ( auto s : result ) {

        while(getline(iss, line)) { 
            curLine++;
            if ((offset = line.find(s, 0)) != string::npos) {
            cout << "found: " << s << " line: " << curLine << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the time you reach `curLine++` you already read 2 lines via `getline(iss, line)` so your line numbers must be off. Also, once you read all lines via the inner `getline` the outer loop has nothing to read anymore.

Instead of trying to jump back and forth in the file you should read it once and then work on data in memory. I would suggest a data structure that holds all data from one line. Something along the line of:

```
struct entry {
    size_t line_number;
    std::array< std::array< int,3> 3> triples;
};
```

Read them, store them in a vector and then calculate the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to count lines when you read them, you need to count *every* line that you read:

```
while (getline(iss,line)) {
    ++curLine;     //   <----------- count here
    string test = line;
    vecstr result = splitOut(test);
    for ( auto s : result ) {

        while(getline(iss, line)) { 
            ++curLine;     //   <----------- as well as here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a map data structure and recording the line numbers of the triples in a vector, the problem becomes easily implemented.

The assumption is that the input is as you've given -- a `{number <triplets>…}`, where `triplets` are the line of triplets, where each triplet has no whitespace between the numbers.

Given all of that, here is a small example with comments:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string test =
"{4 <1,-1,-1> <1,1,-1> <-1,1,-1> <-1,-1,-1>}\n"
"{4 <1,3,-1> <1,1,-1> <1,1,0.5> <1,3,0.5>}\n"
"{4 <1,3,-1> <-1,3,-1> <-1,1,-1> <1,1,-1>}\n"
"{4 <-1,3,-1> <-1,3,0.5> <-1,1,0.5> <-1,1,-1>}\n"
"{4 <1,3,0.5> <1,1,0.5> <0.75,1,1> <0.75,3,1>}\n"
"{4 <-0.75,3,1> <-0.75,1,1> <-1,1,0.5> <-1,3,0.5>}\n"
"{4 <-0.75,3,1> <0.75,3,1> <0.75,1,1> <-0.75,1,1>}\n"
"{4 <1,-1,0.5> <1,-0.75,1> <3,-0.75,1> <3,-1,0.5>}\n"
"{4 <1,-1,0.5> <3,-1,0.5> <3,-1,-1> <1,-1,-1>}\n"
"{4 <1,-1,-1> <3,-1,-1> <3,1,-1> <1,1,-1>}";

int main()
{
    // map of "<x,y,z>" strings to a vector of line numbers where <x,y,z> is found
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> triplet_map;  

    std::istringstream strm(test);
    std::string line;
    std::string triplet;

    int line_number = 1;
    while (getline(strm, line))
    {
        // remove the ending }
        line.pop_back();

        // find the first <
        auto first_pos = line.find_first_of('<');

        // start reading from there
        std::istringstream linestrm(line.c_str() + first_pos);
        while (linestrm >> triplet)
        {
            // insert the triplet in the map if not already there
            // insert() returns an iterator to the inserted item, or the existing
            // item in the map if not newly inserted.
            auto pr = triplet_map.insert({ triplet, std::vector<int>() });

            // record the line number in the vector
            pr.first->second.push_back(line_number);
        }
        ++line_number; // update the line number
    }

    // Output statistics
    for (auto& m : triplet_map)
    {
            // Only output if vector size is > 1
        if (m.second.size() > 1)
        {
            for (auto& v : m.second)
                std::cout << "found: " << m.first << " line: " << v << "\n";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The output would look similar to this:

```
found: <3,-1,-1> line: 9
found: <3,-1,-1> line: 10

found: <3,-1,0.5> line: 8
found: <3,-1,0.5> line: 9

found: <-0.75,1,1> line: 6
found: <-0.75,1,1> line: 7
…
```

Here is a [live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59d31620f8fd96de).